# MS SQL Window Function LAST_VALUE in five Seconds

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I've got the next data Id, received and balance

Now I need to calculate the last column per a period of time, so the last column should be the last value of the balance column within the next five seconds.

```
Id  Received    Balance     LastPerFiveSeconds
171 2015-11-25 10:05:50.630 13548830.86000000   15026517.59000000
172 2015-11-25 10:05:50.760 13590759.43000000   15026517.59000000
173 2015-11-25 10:05:50.790 13632688.00000000   15026517.59000000
174 2015-11-25 10:05:50.850 13662038.00000000   15026517.59000000
175 2015-11-25 10:05:50.910 13687195.15000000   15026517.59000000
176 2015-11-25 10:05:50.940 13703966.58000000   15026517.59000000
177 2015-11-25 10:05:50.950 13720738.01000000   15026517.59000000
178 2015-11-25 10:05:50.990 13762666.59000000   15026517.59000000
179 2015-11-25 10:05:51.060 13787823.73000000   15026517.68000000
180 2015-11-25 10:05:51.200 14987823.73000000   15026517.68000000
181 2015-11-25 10:05:51.360 15026517.68000000   15026517.68000000
182 2015-11-25 10:05:56.630 15034903.39000000   15034903.39000000
```

The query looks like that

```
SELECT id, Received, Balance, LAST_VALUE(Balance) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(S, 5, [Received]) ORDER BY Received  RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM Data
```

Comment: What is your question? Please separate out your "got" from "need".

Comment: Do you mean 5 seconds rather than 5 minutes?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: I need to calculate LastPerFiveMinute from Balance    using Received     as time window

Comment: @TabAlleman I've being using LAST_VALUE(Balance) OVER (ORDER BY Received  RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) but cannot control what is in the time fame

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever 5 minutes, so the LastPerFiveMinute for Id171 should be the balance for id 181

Comment: But all of your sample data occupies a period of 7 seconds during the same minute (10:05), so can you see why I'm confused?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right about it sorry, still how will you apply LAST_VALUE(Balance) OVER (ORDER BY Received RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) within a time range always looking forward

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CROSS APPLY` to achieve what you want. It will look at balances up to five minutes in the future and select the most recent balance:

```
SELECT do.Id ,
      do.Received ,
      do.Balance ,
      ISNULL(details.Balance,do.Balance) AS LastPerFiveMinute
FROM      dbo.data do
      OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                         Balance
                 FROM    dbo.Data di
                 WHERE   di.Received <= DATEADD(MINUTE, 5,
                                            do.Received)
                         AND di.Received >= do.Received
                 ORDER BY    Received DESC
                ) details
ORDER BY Received ASC
```

Comment: really nice answer, the issue is that in larger dataset will run for really long time, I've got thousands transactions on this data set, that's why I was thinking on using window functions

Comment: Not quite right 14112552 is the result of '20151201 15:45:00' and 14112553 for 2015-12-01 15:49:59.000 so they are within 5 minutes but the factor will group them differently

Comment: You can't use `LAST_VALUE` in your case as it is currently not possibly specific `RANGE` values. `LAST_VALUE` also doesn't work when there is a gap (>5 minutes) in your dataset.